# Get attribute of selected <option> in ddSlick dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using your ddslick plugin with select element.

```
<select name="category" id="cat">
    <option cat_type="2" value="cat1" id="hello">Category1</option>
    <option cat_type="1" value="cat2" id="hello2">Category2</option>
</select>
```

In here when select category I need to get selected value **cat_type**. I tried as below.

```
$('#cat').ddslick({
    width: "100%",
    onSelected: function (data) {
        console.log(data.selectedData);    
    }
});
```

OUTPUT

```
Object { text="Category1", value="cat1", selected=true, more...}
```

But **cat_type** attribute is not there. Please help me If someone have experience with **ddslick** plugin.

I have Inspect the html source for the select tag. but It doesn't contain that attribute.

```
<div id="cat" class="dd-container" style="width: 100%;">
   <div class="dd-select" style="width: 100%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);">
     <input type="hidden" class="dd-selected-value" value="cat2"><a class="dd-selected">
     <label class="dd-selected-text">Category2</label></a><span class="dd-pointer dd-pointer-down"></span>
 </div>

 <ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
    <li><a class="dd-option"> <input type="hidden" value="cat1" class="dd-option-value"> <label class="dd-option-text">Category1</label></a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="dd-option dd-option-selected"> <input type="hidden" value="cat2" class="dd-option-value"> <label class="dd-option-text">Category2</label></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It does say "more...". Have you tried `console.log(data.selectedData['cat_type']);`?

Comment: @SandyChapman I tried this, but output is `undefined`

Comment: I think you'll have to use the event object like  `.$(this).attr("cat_type");`

Comment: @brroshan I tried this one also . output is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with the Chrome debugger, it looks like you can do this to access your `cat_type` attribute:

```
$(data.original[0].children[data.selectedIndex]).attr('cat_type')
```

See this JSFiddle for an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/vpwLqtcv/2/

Comment: @KTAnj : I've updated my example and added a JSFiddle. Please give it a try :)

Comment: Did you change anything from the plugin

Comment: No, I'm including the plugin directly from this url: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40036711/Scripts/jquery.ddslick.js which I received when I clicked "download" on the ddslick website.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue..Its not fullly documented